# Can't make TCP client code work without USB cable attached

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm having a bit of trouble in getting a very simple TCP client working on my HTC Titan w/ Windows Phone 7.5.

When the USB cable is attached to the phone, the TCP client works like a charm, but as soon as the cable is unplugged, the client is unable to connect to a TCP server running on my development machine. The devices are on the same network and I'm using the explicit IP-address of my desktop machine to connect, so there's no name resolution going on afaik.

Here's the code I use. Most of it was taken from the Sockets samples on MSDN (can't seem to find the link now though).

```
private Socket _sock = null;
private ManualResetEvent _done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
private const int TIMEOUT = 5000;

//connect to server
public string Connect(string ip, int port) {
    string result = string.Empty;
    var host = new IPEndpoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
    _sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    _sock.SetNetworkRequirement(NetworkSelectionCharacteristics.NonCellular);

    var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    args.RemoteEndPoint = host;
    args.Completed += new EventHandler((s,e) => {
        result = e.SocketError.ToString();
        _done.Set();
    });

    _done.Reset();
    _sock.ConnectAsync(args);
    _done.WaitOne(TIMEOUT);
    return result;
}

//send message
public string Send(string msg) {
    string response = "Operation timeout";
    if (_sock != null) {
        var args= new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.RemoteEndPoint = _sock.RemoteEndPoint;
        args.Completed += new EventHandler(s, e) => {
            response = e.SocketError.ToString();
            _done.Set();
        });

        var payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        args.SetBuffer(payload, 0, payload.Length);

        _done.Reset();
        _sock.SendAsync(args);
        _done.WaitOne(TIMEOUT);
    }

    return response;
}

//receive message
public string Receive() {
    string response = "Operation timeout";

    if (_sock != null) {
        var args= new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.RemoteEndPoint = _sock.RemoteEndPoint;
        args.SetBuffer(new Byte[MAX_BUFSIZE], 0, MAX_BUFSIZE);
        args.Completed += new EventHandler((s,e) => {
            if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
                response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
                response = response.Trim('\0');
            }
            else {
                response = e.SocketError.ToString();
            }

            _done.Set();
    });

    _done.Reset();
    _sock.ReceiveAsync(args);
    _done.WaitOne(TIMEOUT);
    }

    return response;
}
```

The code is then simply used like:

```
Connect(...);
Send(...);
Receive(...);
//and then close the socket
```

As I said before, the code works like a charm when the device is attached to my development machine. When the cable is unplugged, the connection phase just times out (regardless of the timeout interval I should say).

Also, the manifest contains the ID_CAP_NETWORKING capability which as I understand it should give the app permission to access the network.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I discovered that switching to UDP communication works like a charm. Which means that the problem is that for some reason, the phone is unable to set up a persistant TCP connection to my dev machine. This is getting stranger by the minute.

Comment: I have a dumb question. Are the IP packets going across the USB connection when you've got that plugged in? If so, then are you using the correct address for a non-USB (presumably a WiFi) connection? Your desktop machine may be assigning itself a different address for the USB-to-phone connection than for the wireless network.

Comment: Your machine probably uses different IPs for different networks (USB and Wi-Fi). Check that your code when disconnected is using the Wi-Fi address rather than the USB one.

Comment: GregHewgill: Yes they are. And yes I am. As far as I can see, the phone uses the USB connection as a network interface when plugged in. But my dev machine still has the same IP regardless.

Strillo: It's the same address.

Comment: @manneorama: My point is that your dev machine may have **more than one address**. If you are using the same IP address in both situations, then this could be the issue. But I don't really know for sure, since I can't see your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a wireless ap nearby on which your phone is connected? because when you plug it in the pc it uses the pc's network connection.

Comment: Yes, the phone is connected to my WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the IP address that you have on both the phone (from your code) and on the PC (which it looks like you've already found using  `ipconfig` in your command prompt).

These should be in the same IP address range, and so start with the same digits (for IPv4, probably something link `192.168.0.*`).

If this all matches up check your wireless router hasn't enabled a security setting which means that it doesn't allow TCP traffic from your phone to your PC.

If this is a consumer router you manage this should be fairly simple to verify (and potentially fix). If not, you're probably stuck...

Comment: It's in all probability a connectivity issue as you say. However, the phone and the laptop are on the same network which can only mean that the router is trying to route internal traffic through the external network, or something like that. Sadly I'm on a corporate network so I can't really verify that.